# Is it possible to combine RemoteAddrValve and an Authentication valve in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I'd like to implement container-based access control with Apache Tomcat.  I would like to grant access to my web service either by IP address ***or*** by using one of the built-in authenticator valves (e.g. FORM, BASIC, etc.).

The usage scenario is to allow access from some static server IP addresses *or* by some users supplying some authentication credentials (preferably over TLS) if they aren't within those trusted IP ranges.

Is it possible to combine the actions of two valves in this way?  If not what would be a good/quick/simple way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Tomcat does not support this out of the box. You will have to write your own `Authenticator` to do this kind of thing.

For example, since you want to combine an existing `Authenticator` (let's say the `FormAuthenticator` for challenging a user for their username and password via an HTML form) but also allow a bypass for users coming from an IP range, then simply:

1. Subclass the FormAuthenticator
2. Override the `authenticate(Request,HttpServletResponse)` method to

   1. Check the IP request's address; if match, set a `Principal` on the request and `return true`
   2. If no IP match, call `super.authenticate(request,response)`

Have a good look at how `FormAuthenticator.authenticate` does what it does, and you'll easily be able to deal with the `Principal` as described above.

Remember that, if you only have an IP address, you won't know which user or role to choose. So you'll probably need something like "IPauthUser" in whatever collection of roles is appropriate for that user.

Comment: Thanks, Christopher. So basically adding in the `RemoveAddrValve` functionality to a custom valve based on one of the existing `Authenticator` valves?

Comment: Thanks again, Christopher. That's incredibly helpful and your suggestion sounds ideal.  I will take a look as you suggest.

Comment: If you are having any trouble with the actual implementation, join the [Tomcat user's mailing list](https://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-users) and ask-away.